# Space getting inserted during csv.writer

Tags: python-2.7, csv

```
with open('vehicles.csv', 'w') as vehicles:
    ewriter = csv.writer(vehicles, delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    ewriter.writerow('year,plants')
```

I am trying to get year printed in first cell and plants in second. However, instead of "year", "y e a r" gets printed. Why is a space getting inserted between each character and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the string 'year,plants' to the writerow method.
writerow thinks that you are passing in a sequence of characters (which you are, since a string *is* a sequence of characters), and treats each one as a separate column. It then inserts a space between each character because you specified space as your delimiter.

If you want two columns, with 'year' in the first column and 'plants' in the second column, you need to pass in a list of strings, not just a single string:

```
ewriter.writerow(['year', 'plants'])
```